# Calculating KC Given Equilibrium Concentrations

Tags: organic-chemistry

Ex. N2O4(g) 2NO2(g)
• If you place 0.0350 mol N2O4 in 1 L flask at
equilibrium, what is KC?
• [N2O4]eq = 0.0292 M
• [NO2]eq = 0.0116 M

**i want to know from where this coming**

• [N2O4]eq = 0.0292 M

• [NO2]eq = 0.0116 M

Comment: This seems like a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) question. We ‎have a policy which states that you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the ‎problem. It'll make us certain that we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this ‎question may get closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are the concentrations of $\mathbf{N_2O_4}$ and $\mathbf{NO_2}$ at equilibrium. They are just given to you as part of the question for you to use in calculating $K_c$.